# Как ограничить ресурсы в docker-compose

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

Использую Docker version 17.03.0-ce + docker-compose file api v3.
Как можно ограничить используемые ресурсы в docker-compose файле? В частности интересуют RAM и диск

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак. Только через docker run

Answer (score 1):

Это прекрасно описано в [официальной документации](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources)

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpus: '0.001'
    memory: 50M
  reservations:
    cpus: '0.0001'
    memory: 20M
```

Comment: Там же написано что это пишется в deploy. И работает только для кластера. Разве нет?

Comment: @ChizhovRoman можете показать где?

Comment: [вот тут. категория deploy](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#deploy)
Specify configuration related to the deployment and running of services. This only takes effect when deploying to a swarm with docker stack deploy, and is ignored by docker-compose up and docker-compose run.

А resources внутри deploy

Comment: Когда я пытаюсь использовать resources вне deploy, то получаю ошибку 
`Unsupported config option for services.web: 'resources'`